# two fluid divs side by side

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I am trying to align 2 fluid divs side by side here is a preview http://jsfiddle.net/238ha/
of what is looks like now. What I am trying to do, is have two divs

this is the current code

```
.images {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position:absolute;
  top:40px;
  left:0px;
  float:left;
  width: 25%;
  min-width: 305px;
  height: 95%;
}
.content {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position:absolute;
  top:40px;
  left: 25%;
  width:70%;
  min-width: 60%;
  height: 95%;
}
```

Here is what I am trying to accomplish

images:
 takes up 25% of screen

content:
 takes up 75% of screen

However when the user resizes their screen the divs can get bigger, but they have a limit on how small they can get. I have read about flexboxes and I think they might work but their still is not great support for them, and I havent been able to use "flex-flow:row" with any success. I am also using bootstrap alot on the site, so if you know how to do this is bootstrap that would be even better.I appreciate the help.

Comment: You've set a `min-width` in `px` which isn't fluid. Why not set the images inside the `.images` element to `width: 100%; height: auto;` and have the images scale, then remove that `min-width`. You're also using `position: absolute` and `float: left`, you do not need both, you can just use `float: left` and remove your `top` & `left` lines. Remember to add the `float: left` to the .content class.

Comment: @james What I am trying to do is have a mix of both fluid and not fluid, I want the sum of both divs width = 100%, however when the user resizes their screen I want the divs to have a fixed size.

Comment: You're probably going to want to look at responsive design then. Use a fluid layout for anything above the minimum width, and a fixed for below. You should check out [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries) for some help.

Comment: thanks the media queries worked perfectly, if you can post that comment as an answer I will accept it. thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably going to want to look at responsive design. Use a fluid layout for anything above the minimum width, and a fixed for below. You should check out [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries) for some help.

Answer (score -1):

If a div have "float:left" to alling another div you must set "float:left" in its rules too. Becouse if there aren't 
 they are in the same line, so the first go on left and second do the same, but it found in left the first so it will alling to this.